# How to bind an event handler to <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$(".multiple").each(function() {
        $(this).bind("mousedown",function() {
            alert();
        });
    });
```

Here is the HTML it applies to:

```
<select>
<option value = "textbox">TextBox</option>
<option class = "multiple" value = "multiplechoice">MultipleChoice</option>
<option class = "multiple" value = "dropdown">DropDown</option>
</select>
```

I expect to see some sort of alert box, but it doesn't seem to function.  How can I fix this?

Comment: `alert();` is not showing anything, because the first argument is **required**. Specify any parameter to get it to work. Even `void 0` will do the job. I usually use `alert(0)` for quick debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can bind events to `option` elements, as they are drawn by the browser and belong to the [shadow DOM](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/) once rendered (I think). [It doesn't work for me at least in Chrome 17](http://jsfiddle.net/PRuJ6/).

You could, however, do this...

```
$('select').change(function() {
    alert('Selected is ' + $(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bmevw/).

Comment: there's a problem there... the event won't fire when the user clicks on the option that was already selected

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```
$('.multiple').change(function(){
    alert('something');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<select class="multiple">
<option value = "textbox">TextBox</option>
<option  value = "multiplechoice">MultipleChoice</option>
<option  value = "dropdown">DropDown</option>
</select>
```

Comment: there's a problem there... the event won't fire when the user clicks on the option that was already selected

Answer (score 0):

Don't go there - from experience. That's not a cross browser solution.
My suggestion is that on the "change" event of the select, test if the current selected option has the class of "multiple" and if so, run the specific logic.

Comment: there's a problem there... the event won't fire when the user clicks on the option that was already selected

Comment: So he can also register to click on the select and right the same logic only if the srcElement is option tag (instead of the change).

Comment: We'll, my bad. It seems like that in all of the cases the "select" is the srcElement. However, you can look at this fiddle as a solution. What I've done is to register to the click event and now I have control to do part of the logic if the values has changed and other part of they haven't. Basically we have full control:

http://jsfiddle.net/am4ca/

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the event on the select, and filter it by option class

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var o = $(this).find('option:selected');
    if ('multiple' != o.attr('class')) {
        return;
    }
    alert('Clicked: ' + o.text());
});
```

You could also use `click()` instead of `change()` to get clicks that don't result in a change, but you will get the clicks that also drop the select down, that is, if your select is `size="1"`.  That approach would require your event handler to account for false positives, and for that reason, is discouraged.